# json_decode double quotes and commas returns NULL

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use json_decode to decode a json that contains a word with a comma and a word with double quotes:

```
{"wordsFont":"Times New Roman","nameList":["Overflow ,","Stack ""]}
```

json_decode fails so i tried to format the string to escape the quotes with functions like:

```
function fixDoubleQuotedJSON($broken_json)
{
   return str_replace('""','\""',$broken_json);
}
```

but it's only the case where the comma and double quotes are at the end of a word. And the outcome:

```
{"wordsFont":"Times New Roman","nameList":["Overflow \,","Stack \""]}
```

decodes correctly but i need to find a way to do that for any placement of double quotes and commas. any suggestions?

EDIT: this is the initial value in the database:

```
{\"wordsFont\":\"Times New Roman\",\"nameList\":[\"Overflow ,\",\"Stack \\\"\"]}
```

and i can't change the code that generates it to the database

Comment: You'd be better off fixing whatever's generating that not-quite-JSON text. If it was properly built, the extra quotes would have been escaped and you could json_decode() it as expected.

Comment: @MarcB please look at my edit. it's the initial value

Comment: The only suggestion I have is to fix the problem or make whoever created it fix it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was fixed by replacing stripslashes() with urldecode().
This happened because someone previously made use of urlencode().

```
$jsonFix = urldecode($json);
$json = json_decode($jsonFix, true);
```